# Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task':react-native-fs:javaPreCompileDebug'property'compileClasspaths'during up-to-date check

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm trying to build my react-native project into my android device, but it keeps giving me the error (as in the title). I've tried doing this: 
sudo react-native bundle --platform android --devfalse --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
and I've also tried re-running it after that, still gives the same error. This error happened after I rename my app name using this guide: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename.

Comment: Have you walked through all of your Java files to verify that everything was changed properly? Try cleaning the build as well

Comment: Well, in the java code it's still showing package com.companyname, instead of my real company name, should i change that too? @Kai

Comment: If that's the same everywhere, it should still build, but it sounds like the rename may have failed halfway through. Make sure the Java class and manifest package names are consistent and that the directory structure reflects them, that your app/build.gradle is using the correct applicationId, that your app.json and MainActivity have the correct app name

Comment: Okay @Kai all manifest, java, gradle, json and js has all the same name, tried doing this again: sudo react-native bundle --platform android --devfalse --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res now it shows a different error: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-fs:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.